# Как при использовании schedule вернуть значение из job

Tags: python, schedule

Как в данном случае получить значение переменной, которая возвращается из процедуры, выполняемой в планировщике?

```
import schedule
import time

def job(counter):
    print(counter)
    return counter+1


ret_count = 1 //Требуется вернуть
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job, counter=ret_count)

while True:
    print(ret_count)
    schedule.run_pending()    
    time.sleep(1)`
```

Comment: Вернуть куда? в программу которая запускает задачу? вынеси тогда логику обработки этого ответа в саму задачу. Она же планировщиком юзается

Comment: Запускать планировщиком не могу, это тестовый пример, основная программ запускается вне зависимости от регистрации пользователя и необходимо мониторить состояния и возникающие окна. Необходимо вернуть в цикл ret_count, что бы заново передать в job.